How can we use the ltlf2dfa tool to convert a temporal formula with predicate form into a DFA ？
We know that LTL divided into DFA can transform an LTLf formula into a DFA, but when in the context of intelligent planning, the general LTLf formula expressing the timing goal will contain some predicates, these predicates are defined in the domain of PDDL, so they cannot be directly used as the input of LTLf2DFA tool.
Symbolic and variable parts need to be computed: This is the current thinking:
Parse LTLf formula:

need to parse the input LTLf formula. This can be done by writing a parser or using an existing parsing library. The parser will recognize basic elements in the formula such as atomic propositions, logical and temporal operators such as &, U, not, and parentheses.

Identify atomic propositions: In LTLf formulas, atomic propositions are usually represented as predicate(argument1 argument2...). You need to identify these atomic propositions and extract the predicate names and arguments.

Extract predicates: Extract predicates from each atomic proposition. In your example, the predicate is at.

Build Symbol object: For each extracted predicate, you can create a Symbol object that contains the predicate name and its related information. For example, a Symbol might contain predicate names and a list of arguments.

Return a list of Symbols: Finally, collect all extracted symbols into a list and return the list.


But I don't know how to code this in Java or Python

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
